# Access denied when trying to delete a file being accessed only by http

Tags: xml, http, iis, worker-process

I have a folder inside my Website on my Server where XML files are kept.
A User can access the XML files via http (have configured mime type in IIS).

There is a program which generates and updates the XML files on the folder. Occasionally my program gets access denied when trying to delete an XML file from the folder and replace it with a new version.

At times when I have checked manually on the Server using Process Explorer, I have found that the file was locked by an IIS Worker process. If http is stateless why is the IIS Worker process locking the file.

I am 100% sure that the folder containing XML files is not accessed by any other program. Users can only download the XML file over http.

Please let me know if there is a solution for resolving this issue.

Comment: Is it simply locking it when its serving up the file, or if you cut off all users, is it locking it beyond the lifetime of requests?  Also, HTTP doesn't really apply here as HTTP is only the communications between the client and the WebServer, not the WebServer and any other component it needs.

Comment: I am not sure whether IIS is simply locking the file when serving up the file or for some additional time also. If I restart the app pool the lock is freed up. Is there a way of reducing the lock time or giving Users access to the XML in some other way.